# Error when upgrading

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

When I'm running the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It shows the error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libexiv2-14:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libexiv2-14:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and I'm getting the same error. Then I tried removing the package:

```
sudo apt remove libexiv2-14:amd64
[sudo] password for pas:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libraw15 libset-scalar-perl shotwell-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libexiv2-14 libgexiv2-2 shotwell
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 9,233 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 250847 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing shotwell (0.22.0+git20160108.r1.f2fb1f7-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgexiv2-2:amd64 (0.10.3-2) ...
dpkg: error processing package libexiv2-14:amd64 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libexiv2-14:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm getting this;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem, first I  removed the whole package using this command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libexiv2-14
```

And after updating the sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I reinstalled the mentioned package.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libexiv2-14
```